# How do I get exactly same permission as Administrator in UNIX

Tags: linux, unix, permissions, root, administrator

I know there are many solutions online for this question but none of them seem to be clear enough. I want to know is there a way by which I can get same permissions as a unix root administrator. All I am interested in is all the commands should make no difference even if I use sudo or skip sudo infront of them. And so none of the commands should ask me for sudo again.

I had tried changing the visudo file content to this,

```
...
root    ALL=(ALL) ALL
...
...
prathd  ALL=(ALL) ALL
...
```

$whoami returns prathd.

It still didn't make any difference for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a sysadmin question (so off-topic on StackOverflow).

I would suggest to add yourself to the `sudo` group (using `sudo adduser prathd sudo`) then to edit (with `visudo` preferably) the `/etc/sudoers` file and add there:

```
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
#%sudo  ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
%sudo   ALL=NOPASSWD:  ALL
```

Notice that the first `#%sudo` line is commented. The second is adding an important *security risk* (which I accept on my systems): anyone able to become you can go root without typing any password.

Then I can type `sudo make install` without typing any password!

For ordinary things (compilation, browsing, documentation, tests) I am using my usual user id (not root).

I don't think that becoming `uid 0` for your user is a good idea. (For example, don't be root when browsing the web). You really want the protection (at least against stupid mistakes) of being an ordinary user. Typing `sudo` only when you are sure to be `root` is  a convenience.

Comment: It worked for me on my user system UBUNTU. Have to check in for the UNIX RHEL I am using in my office. The visudo file there is a little different. It's auto generated. Thank BTW. :)

Answer (score 1):

> All I am interested in is all the commands should make no difference
>   even if I use sudo or skip sudo infront of them.

What you are trying to do is likely wrong and will weaken security.

That said, an easy solution would be to just change your id in `/etc/passwd` to 0. This will let you retain username and settings (home dir, shell etc) and still have superuser privileges.

Comment: Will I not face any problem changing my UID to 0? And to be sure is that the third field you are referring to?

Comment: @Deepak Third field. Shouldn't encounter any problems, but you might get some weirdness because files don't belong to your user any longer. Still, root should be able to access anything.

Comment: I don't know why but for some strange reason my UID is changing back to the original ID. I tried making it 0 but it is changing back.